# Can't open new activity containing WebView - Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I've seen similar questions to this, but I haven't found any answers that work for me.

Anyway, when I open a new activity, it is going back to a completely different activity - either that or it's crashing the whole app. Here's the relevant code:

**alllistings.java**

```
public void doOpenForum(View view) {
        Bundle extras2 = getIntent().getExtras();
        Intent theIntent2 = new Intent(alllistings.this,forums.class);
        String username2 = extras2.getString("username");
        String password2 = extras2.getString("password");
        theIntent2.putExtra("username", username2);
        theIntent2.putExtra("password", password2);
        startActivity(theIntent2);
}
```

Obviously that's not the whole thing, it's just the actual function. I know that this function does actually get run, because when debugging it, I put a toast inside, and it ran.

**forums.java**

```
package com.slapphappy.gnome;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class forums extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forums);
        WebView htmlObjectForum = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.forumEmbed);
        WebSettings webSettingsForum = htmlObjectForum.getSettings();
        webSettingsForum.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettingsForum.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettingsForum.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        Bundle extrasForum = getIntent().getExtras();
        String allListingsURLForum = "file:///android_asset/embedForum.html?username=" + extrasForum.getString("username") + "&password=" + extrasForum.getString("password");
        htmlObjectForum.loadUrl(allListingsURLForum);
    }
}
```

That bit is not even opening, when I tried putting a toast in the top of it, it didn't even run. Not sure why. I can share the xml in there, but the XML file is correctly named and does exist. I really need help. Thanks in advance.